# Non-decreasing Array List Index out of Range

Tags: python

This is a coding challenge from Daily Interview Pro where you are given an array in arbitrary order, and you have to make it an increasing array with 1 modification to the array or less. This is my code:

```
    def check(lst):
      count = 0
      for i in lst:
        if i == lst[-1]:
          break
        **if i > lst[i+1]:**
          count += 1
      if count <= 1:
        return True
      else:
        return False

    check([13, 4, 7])
    #Should return True
```

The Error is where the stars are. Error: list index out of range. I do not understand this error because I made an if statement for the for loop to break when the for loop gets to the last number. (I have made my indenting correctly, the stars make it look like the indenting is off)

Comment: It's a bit jarring to name that variable `i`. That's traditionally reserved for _indexes_ into lists, not the values within the list. And that seems to be what's caused your confusion—you try to treat it as both an index and a value.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use `i` as both the value of the element in the list (`for i in lst`) and as an index into the list `lst[i+1]`

Comment: show an example of the out put you want to derive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked and the value of 'i' is 13 and your list is only if len 3. The value of 'i' depends on the value at the list index. That's why it is giving an error

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the counter **i** iterates through your list elements - first it becomes *13*, then *4*, and last *7*.

So, when you say **lst[i+1]**, it becomes lst[13+1] == lst[14], which does not exist in your lst, since it goes from lst[0] up to lst[2].

I think you probably mean to iterate using range:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
  ...
```